# FB.logout with server side code session cleanup

Tags: javascript, asp.net, facebook, session, facebook-c#-sdk

I need to fire my server side code after calling the `FB.logout` from Facebook JS sdk. Here's how my html looks

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnSignOut" runat="server" Text="Sign Out" OnClientClick="return Logout();" OnClick="lbtnSignOut_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

and the js code

```
function Logout() {
        var currentToken = "<%= Session["AccessToken"]%>";

        if (currentToken != null && currentToken != '') {

            FB.logout(function (response) {                    
            });
        }

        return true;
    }
```

and subsequently in the server side code, i clear out all application specific session and signs the user out using FormsAuthentication sign out call and redirect to different page.

Now the problem is, the moment I return **true** from the js function, the server side code fires without waiting for fb.logout to complete the call and the user token does not expire and user is automatically logged back in the **FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {};** call in the page load which i have picked from standard code.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                //SUCCESS

                //the user is logged in and has authenticated your
                // app, and response.authResponse supplies
                // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
                // request, and the time the access token 
                // and signed request each expire

                var currentToken = "<%= Session["AccessToken"] %>";


                if (currentToken == null || currentToken == '') {

                    // Handle the access token
                    // Do a post to the server to finish the logon
                    // This is a form post since we don't want to use AJAX
                    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

                    var form = document.createElement("form");
                    form.setAttribute("method", 'post');
                    form.setAttribute("action", '/facebookLogin.ashx');

                    var field = document.createElement("input");
                    field.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                    field.setAttribute("name", 'AccessToken');
                    field.setAttribute("value", accessToken);
                    form.appendChild(field);

                    document.body.appendChild(form);
                    form.submit();
                }
            }
            else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                //FAILED
                console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
            }
            else {
                //UNKNOWN ERROR
                console.log('Logged Out.');
            }
        });
    };
```

while if i set the value to **false**, user is logged out from facebook but my custom code does not fire.

So my question is how to call the server side code after the facebook js sdk logout code has fired?

Any help or pointers will be much appreciated!!!

Paritosh

Answer (score 0):

Put the return true inside the function(response){} block, so that is only called when the FB.logout call returns